# How to dump data written to disk

Tags: linux, hard-drive, dump

### Question :

How to dump data (byte-stream) written from an application to the filesystem ? (something like tcpdump but for IO/file).

Ideally it should be able to "attach" and dump the stream while it is beeing written, without specific configuration of the application.

### Context :

I have a Java application that is deployed on some servers. This app is using JCL+Log4j to log all sort of tech stuff.

On a few of them I'm experiencing a rather ... uncommon problem : frequently, log files are polluted by binary data.

Same app, same config, same hardware, same OS ... different behaviour

My logs are all here : if I process the log file with "strings" every thing is back to normal but as I have, let say 90% of binary rubbish, preprocessing the files takes a huge amount of time.

### Goal :

Beeing able to figure out if the problem is inside the java app/JVM or in the OS/Hardware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use strace, like:

```
strace -p PID -e write -s 1024
```

it will dump the processe's write system calls. With maximum 1024 string size.

Comment: Nice I didn't know about that! I see in the man that write accepts a list of file descriptors to monitor. How would you get the list of opened file descriptors

Comment: Got it : `less /proc/17641/fd`